# How can I set the height of a <tr> based on one of its children without JavaScript?

Tags: html, css

I have a table that contains variable amounts of text in several columns with fixed widths. Some of the columns will allow the text inside of them to grow until it is all showing, but the others will be limited to that height, even if they have text that ends up hidden. Is there any way to do that without any JavaScript?

**A couple notes:**

- I don't know what the text will be so I can't set a concrete height on the row itself.
- Previously, I set the height of the text boxes that couldn't grow to be very small, then found them after the page loaded, set their row height to be a concrete number, and set their height to inherit. That was too slow, though, as I will have a lot of rows.

Here is the shell of a table that kind of shows what I'm going for. I need to know how to write out the classes.

```
    <table>
        <tr class="rowCanGrow">
            <td class="canGrowTD" style="width:90px;">
                <div class = "canGrow">Should see all of this text.</div>
            </td>
            <td class = "cantGrowTD" style="width:80px;">
                <div class = "cantGrow">Should see all of this text.</div>
            </td>
            <td class="canGrowTD" style="width:100px;">
                <div class = "canGrow">(Controller) Should see all of this text.Should see all of this text.</div>
            </td>
            <td class = "cantGrowTD" style="width:100px;">
                <div class = "cantGrow">This one should get cut off mid sentence, and definitely shouldn't be allowed to grow as far down as it wants to grow.</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**Edit** Added a space so that the words break correctly and the width's stay consistent, since it's unrelated to what I'm trying to solve.

**Edit 2** Clearing up some things. The cells should all have fixed widths (added inline styling) and note that I won't be able to set a concrete height anywhere because I won't know what that is until the text has rendered and set it.

**Edit 3** Here is the desired result: [image: Resulting Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do this as it turns out. Here is the solution:

```
td {
    vertical-align:top;
}
.cantGrowTd {
    height:100% !important;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.cantGrowTd div.cantGrow {
    position:absolute;
    height:100% !important;
    max-height: initial !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

You can most likely ignore the "important" statements as they are not required unless your td elements and divs are setting their own properties that need to be overridden (as mine do in my actual application).

Answer (score 1):

You can set to you `div` height and width as 100%, with `overflow: hidden;` to hide scrollbar. Second, you should set the any height of your `<td>`. So, basically the div's height is that of the containing cell and the text cannot grow the div, keeping the cell/row the same height no matter what the window size is.

```css
td.canGrowTD > div {
  width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow:hidden;
}

td.canGrowTD {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
        <tr class="rowCanGrow">
            <td class="canGrowTD">
                <div class = "canGrow">Should see all of this text.</div>
            </td>
            <td class = "canGrowTD">
                <div class = "cantGrow">Should see all of this text.</div>
            </td>
            <td class="canGrowTD">
                <div class = "canGrow">(Controller)Should see all of this text.Should see all of this text.</div>
            </td>
            <td class = "canGrowTD">
                <div class = "cantGrow">This one should get cut off mid sentence, and definitely shouldn't be allowed to grow as far down as it wants to grow.</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: This won't work for two reasons. First, there will be a width associated with each <td>. Second, I can't set a concrete height on the <td> because I won't know what that height should be. I'll update my post to be more clear.

Comment: @StevenWojcio you can ANY height as you want, for example `height: 1px;`, and `width` is 100%, that mean `td` contain the 100% of parent - your td will remain the same

Comment: The height of the row is growing to match the tallest cell instead of cutting off the cells marked 'cantGrow'

Comment: @StevenWojcio sorry I remover `.cantGrow` if you add this class, text of this divs works as before